# Why won't it write to the file?

Tags: python-3.x

So I have the code:

```
def logdata(x, y):
    try:
        f = open('multlog.txt', 'a')
        f.write("{0:g} * {1:g} = {2:g}\n".format(x,y, (x*y)))
    except ValueError:
        f.write("Error, you tried to multiply by something that wasn't a number")
        raise
    finally:
        f.close()
print("This is a test program, it logs data in a text file, 'multlog.txt'")
fn = input("Enter the first number you'd like to multiply by: ")
sn = input("Enter the second number you'd like to multiply by: ")
logdata(int(fn), int(sn))
```

And what I want it to do, is when it reaches a value error, for it to write to the file,"Error, you tried to multiply by something that wasn't a number". But, if the file reaches a value error if the user inputs a letter, say "j",`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'j'`, it doesn't write to the file!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least two problems:

1. The file is not open for writing (or appending) in the `except` block.
2. As @DSM points out in a comment, the ValueError is being raised when you call `int()`

I would rewrite to something like the below example.
If you use the `with` statement then you can do without the `finally` block.

```
def logdata(x, y):
    with open('multlog.txt', 'a') as f:
        try:
            x = int(x); y = int(y)
            f.write("{0:g} * {1:g} = {2:g}\n".format(x,y, (x*y)))
        except ValueError:
            f.write("Error")

print("This is a test program, it logs data in a text file, 'multlog.txt'")
fn = input("Enter the first number you'd like to multiply by: ")
sn = input("Enter the second number you'd like to multiply by: ")
logdata(fn, sn)
```

Comment: still doesn't do it even if i put f = open('multlog.txt', 'a') in the except block...

Comment: I think the error is elsewhere: the ValueError is being raised at the int() call, not inside the function, so it's not being caught.

Comment: Thanks, @DSM. Just noticed that, too. Edited answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, as I am a beginner, I don't really know what the as and with statements mean. Could you please explain them?

Comment: @user1247509: Sure. The `with` statement ensures that the file is closed at the end of the `with` block; even if an exception occurs.  Basically you get a try/finally block for free. More detail here in case you're interested: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/